# scrape data using keyword Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrape

I have this code using Python `Requests` library:

```
import requests 

test_URL = "https://www.gasbuddy.com/station/194205"

def get_data(link):
    hdr = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
    req = requests.get(link,headers=hdr)
    content = req.content()
    print(content)

get_data(test_URL)
```

On the website: `https://www.gasbuddy.com/station/194205` there is a section `Regular` which shows the `regular` price for gas. I want to grab that value, but have never done this before so am not sure how I would enter a `keyword` query perhaps within the get request? Any pointers or help on how to?

Comment: have you tried using beautiful soup to scrape the site for certain class elements of where `Regular` and `regular` appear on the site?

Comment: use one of module for `XML`/`HTML`: ie. `BeautifulSoup`, `lxml`, `PyQuery`, etc. You should see some of them in many tutorials (and questions on Stackoverflow) about scraping

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to check if you are human - and this can make problem. It may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website has a few mechanisms inplace to prevent webscraping (or to make it harder):

You can use bs4 to analyse the response you get with requests.
(pip install beautifulsoup4 https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gasbuddy.com/station/194205"
hdr = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
resp = requests.get(url, headers=hdr)
```

After getting the response you can use `soup.select` like this to extract the price for regular and premium

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
regular, premium = (item.text for item in soup.select('span[class*="FuelTypePriceDisplay-module__price___"]'))
```

At the time writing you get:

```
('152.9¢', '162.9¢')
```